# URL rewrite to point to same link and avoid redirect to default page

Tags: asp.net, .net, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I have an application for which the source code is missing. So I am moving the compiled version from source server and hosting as a web application in IIS on the target server. Unfortunately on the target server I see weird redirects happening. Every time when I login to site and click on a specific 'Batch' tab, I get redirected to login page. However this doesn't happen all the time. I am not sure why this is happening on the specific target server and not on the source server.

The link I click: https://mydomain/app1/batch.aspx
I get redirected to : https://mydomain/app1/login.aspx which is set as default doc in web.config.

Can I use URL rewrite to retain the control on Batch page and prevent redirect to login page? Can someone pls mention the steps? I have URL rewrite plugin installed already. Any other suggestions are also most welcome.

Comment: Could you please tell me which kinds of Authentication mode you have used now? Form auth, windows auth or build-in auth. In my opinion. I think url rewrite will not solve your issue. As far as I know, there is a build-in feature that will check the the user is login or not, if user doesn't login it will redirect the user to login page. So if you use url rewrite to rewrite the user to another page, it will still check the login status and redirect to the login page. The right way is check why it still go to the login page even if the user has already  login in.